# Replacing button with imagebutton

Tags: android, bluetooth

So I am working on some code that a friend has left me (I have very little knowledge on this stuff) and have a question regarding Buttons and ImageButtons;

This code is for an app that requires you to click the 'connect' button to enter into a list of bluetooth devices. Once selected you are returned to the home screen and the button now says 'Disconnect'.

Basically, what I want to do is change it from a text based button to an Image button so that I can have a bluetooth icon (black) and when connected change to a connected bluetooth icon (white).

I have the icons and I understand the basic workings for a typical button however this code is a bit much for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have attached the initial sample of java for reference. The btnConnectDisconnect is the name of the button that I wish to replace.

```
        // Handler Disconnect & Connect button
    btnConnectDisconnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!mBtAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onClick - BT not enabled yet");
                Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            } else if (btnConnectDisconnect.getText().equals("Connect")) {
                //Connect button pressed, open DeviceListActivity class, with popup windows that scan for devices
                Intent newIntent = new Intent(UartActivity.this, DeviceListActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(newIntent, REQUEST_SELECT_DEVICE);
            }
            else if (btnConnectDisconnect.getText().equals("Disconnect")) {
                //unpair
                System.out.println("Disconnecting from peripheral");
                pDeviceAddress = null;
                editor.remove("address");
                editor.commit();
                System.out.println("Currently saved address: " + prefs.getString("address", null));
                System.out.println("Currently saved address check: " + pDeviceAddress);
                //disconnect from service
                Thread thread = new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            sleep(50);
                            mService.disconnect();
                            System.out.println("Disconnecting from service...");
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };
                thread.start();

                if(mService == null){
                    System.out.println("Service disconnected!");
                } else System.out.println("Service connected!");
```

Comment: You should just replace it in the layout / xml files, they basically behave the same

Comment: And from the documentation for ImageButton - ["To indicate the different button states (focused, selected, etc.), you can define a different image for each state"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) using an XML selector element

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code, I can see that the button's name is `btnConnectDisconnect`. So what you can do is go into the XML file where this button is put and first replace the button tag (`<Button .../>`) with `<ImageButton..../>`.  You can then add `android:src="@drawable/name_of_drawable"`, to the ImageButton tag, to set the image you want the ImageButton to have. Then go back into the code and change the type of `btnConnectDisconnect` from `Button` to `ImageButton`. This should get you to where you want to go without having to touch the code inside the OnClickListener.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! I now get an error on the else if comments

<blink>
} else if (btnConnectDisconnect.getText().equals("Connect")) {
                //Connect button pressed, open DeviceListActivity class, with popup windows that scan for devices
                Intent newIntent = new Intent(UartActivity.this, DeviceListActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(newIntent, REQUEST_SELECT_DEVICE);
            }
            else if (btnConnectDisconnect.getText().equals("Disconnect")) {
</blink>

Answer (score 0):

To get your desired behavior, there are a few things you need to do.

1. Change the type from Button to ImageButton in your Java file (posted above)
2. Create a new XML file (btn_bluetooth.xml) in the res/drawable directory with the following contents, making sure you replace the image references:

```xml
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item 
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/BLUETOOTH_CONNECTED_IMAGE_REFERENCE"
    />
<item 
    android:state_selected="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/BLUETOOTH_DISCONNECTED_IMAGE_REFERENCE""
    />
</selector>
```

3. Change the type from Button to ImageButton in your XML layout file (usually referenced in the onCreate or onCreateView method of your Java file (posted above)
4. When you establish or lose a bluetooth connection, simply call btnConnectDisconnect.setEnabled() with true or false

Comment: Thank you for the response. When I input your suggestions the else if rule for the disconnect rule gives an error 'else' without if' as well as ')' expected at the other end of the line.

Comment: I cannot get this to work as it throws the above errors

Comment: It sounds like you have a typo somewhere around the if statement. Revert that file back to the way you had it and modify it again from the beginning, being careful not to delete any parentheses.